# Using Recurly payment form with React results in large blank iFrames. Styling removes fields

Tags: reactjs, recurly

[Recurly instructions on how to build a form](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/getting-started-1)

[Github repository that demonstrates the problem.](https://github.com/polkhovsky/react-recurly-form-problem)

My form:

```
<form id="recurly_form">

          <div data-recurly="number"></div>
          <div data-recurly="month"></div>
          <div data-recurly="year"></div>
          <div data-recurly="cvv"></div>
          <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit} >
            Place order
          </button>
        </form>
```

I make every attempt to make sure the `configure` call is made after everything is mounted and ready:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $(() => {
      window.recurly.configure({
        publicKey: "ewr1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      });
    });
  }
```

The end result is a tall blank screen with a button:
[image: What the user sees]

Markup looks like this:
[image: Recurly generated markup]

Note that the month field is set to visibility:hidden. Also note that the `<div data-recurly="number"></div>` is empty. That is the result of me trying to style it with the styles offered in the instructions.

Please advise on what's missing.

Comment: Reply from support: "Since integrating the React framework with Recurly.js is generally unsupported and out of our scope, I recommend [that] you try to mimic the GitHub examples, to see if you can successfully integrate that code with React."

Comment: It would be good to have a proper React integration. I wonder if they will ever come round to it.